# Command not found after creating symbolic link OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I've created a symbolic link: `sudo ln -s ../../Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/tools.sh /usr/local/bin/n`. The symbolic link is added to the system: `lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 57B Jul 27 09:05 n -> ../../Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/tools.sh`. But when I type "n" inside my terminal it says: `command not found: n`. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A relative link would be useful only from a given directory, and then only if the current directory **`.`** (referred to as *dot*) were in your `PATH` variable.  Unless your shell initialization set that explicitly, on OSX you won't have *dot* in `PATH`.

The *dot* may be explicit:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:.
```

or implicit.  For example, if `PATH` were one of the following, it would implicitly use *dot*:

```
:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin::/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Further reading: the discussion of `PATH` in POSIX [8.3 Other Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).

Comment: My `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.